# Add previously deleted Tomcat 7 server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tomcat7, m2eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Luna & I added Tomcat 7 server from Eclipse. But then I deleted it & now I cannot add it back. When I click, add new server & select Tomcat 7, the server name is coming empty & I don't see "Finish" button enabled to add this Tomcat 7 server. Previously, it was showing as "Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost" but since I deleted it, its no longer coming & I cannot add it at all.

Any help is much appreciated to add Tomcat 7 server in Eclipse.

Thanks

Comment: @MikeIs it solve your problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I face the same problem before please follow this steps :

- In Eclipse ***Window–>Preferences–>Server–>Runtime Environments*** and delete server definition from there.
- Change directory to workspace.
- Then under workspace folder follow this path ***.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings*** folder delete  ***org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs***
- At the same directory delete ***org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs***.
- Restart Eclipse

After that try to define new server definition it should be OK.

Comment: for my eclipse Kepler,  it worked without deleting the metadata entries

Comment: Thanks man, this fix is still working for Eclipse Enterprise Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0) with apache tomcat 9 on Mac!

Answer (score 2):

1. Close Eclipse
2. In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings. 
   delete the following two files

   - org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
   - org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs